# How to apply format as 'Text' and 'Accounting' using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I have been using xlsxwriter for a while and find it to be really helpful.
I have used it for multiple purposes like custom data validation, custom formats etc
However there are two things i am not able to perform.

1. set format of a cell to 'text' and not 'general'. i have tried the apis write_string, write_blank but they always apply the format general
2. set format as accounting. i have tried add_format({'num_format': '#,###'}. but this simply sets the format as 'custom' instead of accounting

Please help.

Comment: Have you read http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#set_num_format?

Answer (score 21):

1. To set a cell format to `text` you need to apply a `text` format to the cell (just like in Excel). To do this you set the `num_format` property of the format to '@'.
2. If you set a string format like `#,###` then this will generally show up in Excel as a `custom` format even if it equates to one of the built-in formatting categories like `accountancy`. This is the same behaviour as Excel.

In order to get one of the built-in formats you need to use a format `index` instead of a string. The table in the [num_format section of the docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html?highlight=set_num_format#set_num_format) shows the available indices and their equivalent string formats. For `accountancy` you need to use one of the accountancy-like format indices such as 44 (`_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)`). The example below shows both of these:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 44})

worksheet.write(0, 0, 1234)
worksheet.write(1, 0, 1234, format1)
worksheet.write(2, 0, 1234, format2)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Update**: See also this newer, more specific, section of the XlsxWriter docs on [Number Format Categories](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-format-categories).

Comment: Thank you so much... straight frm the author too.. :)   you are a life savior

Comment: Great answer. The reference to the oficial documentation is correct but the info of `Index 44` for `Accounting` makes the diference here. Thanks

Comment: Can one format the column after the fact? Say, 
` currency = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 44})

worksheet.set_column(df.columns.get_loc('total_cost'), None, currency)`